# Zend_Service_Twitter - use its OAuth functionality to obtain an Access Token before attempting any API

Tags: php, zend-framework, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm Trying to develop a module with Zend that will look up for my latest tweets and display on my Blog.

I've read and learned about `Zend_Service_Twitter` and with this class I suppose I should get latest tweets form my twitter.

when I launch this code given below:

```
public function indexAction() {

        $token = unserialize('XXXXX');      
        $twitter = new Zend_Service_Twitter(array(
             'username' => 'XXX',
             'accessToken' => $token,
             'consumerKey' => 'XXXX',
             'consumerSecret' => 'XXXX',
             'callbackUrl' => 'http://localhost/zendtest/public/blog'
         ));            

        // verify user's credentials with Twitter
        $response = $twitter->account->verifyCredentials();

        // Get Timeline
        $response = $twitter->status->userTimeline();

        $this->view->twitresponse = $response;

    }
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Fatal error:
 Uncaught exception 'Zend_Service_Twitter_Exception' with message 'Twitter session is unauthorised. You need to initialize Zend_Service_Twitter with an OAuth Access Token or use its OAuth functionality to obtain an Access Token before attempting any API actions that require authorisation' in D:\Server\xampp\htdocs\zendtest\library\Zend\Service\Twitter.php:282

Stack trace: 
 #0 D:\Server\xampp\htdocs\zendtest\library\Zend\Service\Twitter.php(769): Zend_Service_Twitter->_init() 
 #1 [internal function]: Zend_Service_Twitter->accountVerifyCredentials()
 #2 D:\Server\xampp\htdocs\zendtest\library\Zend\Service\Twitter.php(270): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
 #3 [internal function]: Zend_Service_Twitter->__call('verifyCredentia...', Array) 
 #4 D:\Server\xampp\htdocs\zendtest\application\modules\twitter\controllers\TwitterServiceController.php(27): Zend_Service_Twitter->verifyCredentials() 
 #5 D:\Server\xampp\htdocs\zendtest\library\Zend\Controller\Action.php(516): Twitter_TwitterServiceController->indexAction() 
 #6 D:\S in D:\Server\xampp\htdocs\zendtest\library\Zend\Controller\Plugin\Broker.php on line 336
```

I've lots of articles on the Internet and here but still can't resolve my problem.

Does anyone know how do deal with this issue?
And what's in common with `Zend_Oauth_Consumer`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only want to show your **own** timeline, you could request the Tokens "directly" on the Twitter Developer pages, and "hardcode" it into your application. So you dont have to deal with redirects and auth process. Try this: (untested because iam on the run..)

```
    $token = new Zend_Oauth_Token_Access();

    $token->setParams(array(
        'oauth_token'        => 'oAUTH-TOKEN',
        'oauth_token_secret' => 'oAUTH-TOKEN-SECRET',
    ));

    $twitter = new Zend_Service_Twitter(array(
        'username'       => 'USER',
        'consumerKey'    => 'CONSUMER-KEY',
        'consumerSecret' => 'CONSUMER-SECRET',
        'accessToken'    => $token
    ));


    $timeLine = $twitter->status->userTimeline();
```